# Bone-rattling vs. bumpy

Tags: adjectives

As an ESL, I only know that when the road your travelling on is rough, I describe it as "**bumpy**".

> Road in provinces is usually **bumpy.**

Compared to:

> Road in provinces is usually **bone-rattling.**

Is there any differences between the two? Or is "bone-rattling" just an advanced english vocabulary?

Answer (score 1):

"Bumpy" is a normal way to describe a rural, unpaved road. "Bone-rattling" is flowery language that emphasizes that the road is extremely bumpy.

For the record, your example sentences don't make sense.
I think you are trying to refer to roads in remote or undeveloped locations. "In provinces" doesn't mean that. And you also have the problem of noun-verb agreement between "Roads" and "is". A better example is

> Rural roads are usually **bumpy**.

Comment: "Provincial roads" is consistent with the original poster's intent.

Comment: Moreover, I'd add: _the road is bumpy; the journey over the road would be bone-rattling._

Comment: I've never heard "bone-rattling," only "bone-**jarring**."

Comment: @Todd, your using the "**rural"** word while mine is "**provincial**" maybe it depends on the country we come from because they are both the same actually. Also, what's wrong with "*provincial road IS*"? It's *uncountable* so it's still correct right?

Comment: @HiddenBabel, I had seen "bone-jarring" by googling before I asked the question above. The source of the word "bone-rattling" is from The Economist, you know that? The speaker of that video is a female, native English user.

Comment: @JohnArvin You can say ***the*** *road in* ***(this / the) province*** *is* or you can say ***(this / the)*** *provincial road is* but you can't say *road in provinces*. If you're talking about multiple roads, you need to say ***roads*** *in provinces* ***are*** or *provincial* ***roads are***.

Comment: Ok. My bad. Thx